# Trouble matching two occurrences of the same pattern using regex

Tags: c#, regex, t-sql

I've got a SQL query as a string, and I'm trying to do some find and replace on it using regex.

```
var s = "SELECT ([Document].[ArtifactID]) FROM [Document]
        (NOLOCK) WHERE [Document].[AccessControlListID_D] 
        IN (1) AND ((NOT EXISTS(SELECT CodeArtifactID 
        FROM CodeArtifact (NOLOCK) WHERE AssociatedArtifactID = 
        [Document].[ArtifactID] AND CodeArtifact.CodeTypeID = 1000112))) ";
//line breaks added for readability
```

In order for the query to work, I need to specify the schema of [Document] and CodeArtifact. I have:

```
var pattern = "FROM\\s(?<table>\\S+)";
var replacePattern = "FROM EDDSDBO.${table}";

var v = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, replacePattern);
System.Console.WriteLine(v);
```

But the string I'm getting back looks like:

```
SELECT ([Document].[ArtifactID]) 
FROM [Document] (NOLOCK) 
WHERE [Document].[AccessControlListID_D] IN (1) AND 
((NOT EXISTS(SELECT CodeArtifactID 
             FROM EDDSDBO.CodeArtifact (NOLOCK) 
             WHERE AssociatedArtifactID = [Document].[ArtifactID] AND CodeArtifact.CodeTypeID = 1000112)))
```

The CodeArtifact was replaced, but the [Document] was not. I must be missing something. Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry but this works for me, just tested it.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Looks like it was a case of sneaky extra whitespace.

Comment: You should not construct SQL queries directly from strings. It opens up all sorts of security holes. There are better methods of construction SQL queries than using string manipulation and/or regular expressions.

Comment: You're right, but I'm getting this string from a web service. If I had my druthers, I'd be doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. The only issue that I can think of is that there's more than one space between `FROM` and `[DOCUMENT]` in your source code, in which case you can either remove the space or use

```
FROM\\s+(?<table>\\S+)
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I tried counting spaces with my cursor, but I guess I missed it.